# List docker repositoris in GCR using golang

Tags: docker, go, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I want to use `go` to list all my repositories in GCR.

I have come across [this](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-containerregistry) library.

However, the only `List` [function](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-containerregistry/pkg/v1/google#List) I see seems to be for listing images/tags for a specific repo. (i.e. it requires a priori knowledge of the repo name / url)

Any idea if there is an option for listing repositories (so that one can later list the images for each repo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`remote.Catalog` function](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-containerregistry@v0.7.0/pkg/v1/remote#Catalog) for listing repositories.

See [example usage](https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/blob/88f6c0099e6ea743c7436f5040b68c465cbf2bf1/pkg/crane/catalog.go#L34) in the `crane` CLI program.

Comment: Thanks. This however fails `registry, err := gcr.NewRegistry("https://gcr.io/my-gcp-project-123")` (have tried without the `https` as well. `gcr` is the following import `"github.com/google/go-containerregistry/pkg/name"`. Any idea what format should I use for my `gcr` repo name? (trying to create the `Registry` before calling `Catalog`

Comment: nvm this worked `my-gcp-project-123.gcr.io`

Comment: Nonetheless when calling `repos, err := remote.Catalog(ctx, registry)` I get the following `GET jttps://my-gcp-project-123.gcr.io/v2/` unexpected status code `404` Not Found. Invalid host name `my-gcp-project-123.gcr.io`. Any ideas?

Comment: You only specify `gcr.io`. You do not need to specify your GCR project, as it will be pulled from your gcloud config.